# Does Sum calculate all terms before summing them?

Tags: summation, memory

After calculating the sum of a large number of large objects, using

```
B = Sum[RandomInteger[{0, 1}, {10^6}], {100}];
```

I find that `MaxMemoryUsed[]` has increased by 400MB, which is about 100 times `ByteCount[B]`. This seems to mean that Mathematica has calculated all terms in the sum before adding them up (equivalent to `Plus@@Table[...]`), rather than keeping a running total. Is this correct?

Because of memory constraints, I need to calculate the sum using a running total. I can obviously do it procedurally (`Do[B+=..., {10^2}]`), but is there a better way?

And, just out of interest, why does Mathematica do it this way? It's not obvious that it's ever significantly more (time) efficient, and in some cases it will be much less (memory) efficient.

Comment: Look at your code, it completes the inner function first.
Loops are pretty minimalistic, since it's c language. I doubt there's a faster way.

Comment: `Sum` is a very complex function that will try to be smart and use the best method for the situation.  This can be symbolic, or dumb sequential summation, etc.  If you need precise control over how to do it, don't use `Sum`.  For you particular use case I'd never use `Sum`, which is really meant for symbolic calculations.  I'd use `Total` or `Apply[Plus]` if memory is not an issue and I'd use a procedural accumulation (`Do`) if it is an issue.  Some might prefer something like `Nest` as an alternative to `Do`.

Comment: To answer the question in the title: with the setting `Method -> "Procedural"`, yes. Otherwise, it tries a number of clever symbolic manipulations depending on the form of the summand. In your case, you are hammering nails with a screwdriver. Use `Total[]`, as suggested in previous comments.

Comment: I was originally using `Plus@@Table[...]` (or something like that), until I realized memory was a problem. Given how clever `Sum` is, I was rather hoping it might be able to take advantage of not needed to store the list (unlike `Table`).

Comment: `RandomVariate[BinomialDistribution[100, 1/2], 1*^6]` accomplishes same thing as your sum. Also, avoid uppercase initials in your symbols, might clash with built-ins.

Comment: Thanks, @ciao, but the code above is a minimal example, not the case I'm actually interested in.

Comment: I guess without knowing the details of the real case it is hard to suggest a better way.